# C writing a linked list to a file

Tags: c, list, pointers

I would like to write all the integer values in the linked list on an individual line, I have a start but multiple errors and I am not sure where to go from here.

```
struct ListNode {
    int value;
    struct ListNode * next;
};        

int llist_save(LinkedList * list, char * file_name) {
    ListNode *e = list->head;
    FILE * fd = (file_name, "w");
    while(e != NULL){
        fprintf(fd, "%d\n", e->value);
        e = e->next;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: It might help to provide the errors, but to start with, check how you open the file.

Comment: "ListNode *e = list->head;" should be "struct ListNode *e = list->head;" unless you use a typedef for the struct declaration. The same applies to the paramater LinkedList *list in the llist_save() function.

Comment: See: [**Writing a linked list to binary file(C)**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444803/writing-a-linked-list-to-binary-filec) and [**Writing data from a linked list to a binary file using fwrite.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435767/writing-data-from-a-linked-list-to-a-binary-file-using-fwrite)

Answer (score 0):

use `fopen()`; try:

```
struct ListNode {
      int value;
      struct ListNode * next;
};        

int llist_save(LinkedList * list, char * file_name) {
    struct ListNode *e = list->head;
    FILE * fd = fopen(file_name, "w");
    while(e != NULL){
        fprintf(fd, "%d\n", e->value);
        e = e->next;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check out a couple of things:

When you declare a structure, you are basically defining a custom-user type.
So, everytime you want to create a new variable of that type you need to put the reserved word `struture` before the name of the structure. Based on your code, that will be something like this: `struct ListNode *e;`

Then, you're trying to send to your function a `LinkedList` parameter. But, I think is more easy if you send a `struct ListNode *` parameter instead, so in that way you are going to "know" what is the first element in the list. But, the method you used is also valid.

Talking about functions, you are declaring a `int` return-type function. In your code, you didn't put the `return` statement. If you don't want to return a value, just change the return type to `void`. Otherwise, just return an integer.

Finally just use `fopen`, that is a function that helps you to open a file in the system. The first paramter in that function is the name of the file you want to open/create and the second paramenter is the 'way' (technically called 'mode') you want to open it. Just send "w", that means write.

You said that you want write the values in a sigle line.To do that ommit the `\n` character in your print statement and print a `' '` (space character).

Some code:

```
struct ListNode 
{
    int value;
    struct ListNode * next;
};        

void llist_save(LinkedList * list, char * file_name) 
{
    struct ListNode *e = list->head;
    FILE * fd = fopen(file_name, "w");

    while(e != NULL) {
        fprintf(fd, "%d ", e->value);
        e = e->next;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

My brain cannot process English very well right now; sorry about that.